# Angular 7 Reactive form with innerHTML

Tags: angular, primeng, angular-reactive-forms

I am using Primeng editor in my Angular 7 application.

```
<p-editor formControlName="description" [style]="{'height':'320px'}"></p-editor>
```

I am setting the value of the control using patchValue like:

```js
const desc = '<strong>Hello World</strong>';

this.form.patchValue({
  description: desc
});
```

Another use case:

```
const desc = '<ul><li>Test 1</li><li>Test 2</li><li>Test 3</li></ul>'
```

In the above case, the p-editor should render it as:

- Test 1
- Test 2
- Test 3

But my reactive form is removing all the HTML formatting and assigning only "Hello World" to the control.
I need to preserve the HTML formatting coming from the server.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can set this as font-weight in style itself. Have you tried that?

Comment: its not specific to font weight. If my data consists of a list, then it should get rendered as list in the p-editor component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't find a proper solution but you can try this hack:

```
<p-editor #myEditor formControlName="description" [style]="{'height':'320px'}"></p-editor>
```

and in ts file

```
import { Editor } from 'primeng/primeng';

@ViewChild('myEditor') myEditor: Editor


const desc = '<strong>Hello World</strong>';

this.form.patchValue({
  description: desc
});

// this will replace innerHTML with service data
this.myEditor.e1.nativeElement.querySelector('ql-editor').innerHTML = desc;
```